# How to write query for this?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi friends I have a table like this

```
ID  bid   sub_bid  cid  sub_cid
1    0       2      1       0
2    5       0      3       0
3    3       0      0       4
4    2       0      4       0
```

on that table either (bid or sub_bid) OR (cid or sub_cid) will be null. I have to write a query for fetching like this..
if bid is zero then I have to take sub_bid or sub_bid is zero then I have to take bid
same incase of cid also.

How can I give this kind of a condition in my mysql query. any one can help me please.
thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example or two of the expected result?  I am confused when you say you have to "take sub_bid".

Comment: Are you taking `zero` and `NULL` to mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `CASE WHEN` statement:

```
   SELECT
    CASE WHEN bid is NULL or bid = 0
     sub_bid 
    ELSE 
     bid end 
    as abid
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL if statements for this. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)